# how to build errors like that shown in Androffice screenshots

Tags: android, validation

Anyone knows how to build errors like that shown in [Androffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtOdW.png) screenshots on AppBrain ([http://www.appbrain.com/app/android.androffice][2])?

I think that I saw errors like that before. Is that built in Android SDK?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it out that I can call `mEditField.setError("Error message for field");` on field.

And... yes mechanism is build into Android. For sure it's available from Android API v1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a built-in thing for Android, but you should be able to get the basics by adding an [`android:drawableRight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) to your `EditText`, to show a warning icon.

It's hard to tell from the screenshow how that error then appears.  Is it when the user clicks on the icon, or when the error happens it appears briefly like a toast?

So it's possible that adding a [customised `Toast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) could be useful here too.

**Edit:**
It seems that a [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) would be a better fit, in comparison to a `Toast`.

Also, you can always run Androffice on your device, then run [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to inspect exactly how they are building the UI.